# Is there an app which can track sleep time automatically in the background?

Tags: android, health

I used to use samsung cell phones. The app s health will suggest a sleep duration every morning when you wake up. You don't need to click anything, open any apps, 'start' anything, just need to sleep, and it will record the time for you.

I guess it reckon the sleep and wake up time based on the activity on your phone. If you stop using the phone, it assume you are asleep. When you start using the phone, it assume you have woken up.

I cannot find an app which can do the same. Most of them need to click start before you sleep, and record it manually when you wake up. I think it's really stupid.

Is there any apps which can do the same as s health?

Thanks.

Comment: You can also take a look at my corresponding app list: [Alarm Clocks with Sleep Monitoring](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/multimedia_alarmclocks#group_361) while waiting for answers :)

Comment: Anytime. If you find a match, please consider to [answer your own question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) then :)

Comment: well, unfortunately, still can't find a match

Comment: Then I could only recommend what I'm using: A Pebble with Gadgetbridge on the Android end (GB is a very pricavy oriented software: no cloud ever, not even the Internet permission). Gives you sleep stats automatically. Also works with a bunch of other trackers, such as MiBand or the AmazBit you get for ~50 bucks. Which of those supports sleep tracking you'd need to check for yourself ;)